# Trying to output a loop of rows inside a table via Jquery and a target div tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table, rows

I have an HTML table, I have wrapped a div tag around 1 of the rows, so that jQuery can replace that w/ row/rows from my PHP output..

Here's what that table looks like in code (easier to view here):

[image: http://d.pr/i/QzfH]

My jQ loads

```
$("#points_details_data").load("points_view.php?eid=<?php echo $eid;?>");
```

and PHP outputs this actual code:

```
<tr><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>test</td>
    <td align='right' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>- 100</td>
</tr>
```

but the resulting display/render is that the PHP output is outside of the target div..see here for screenshot of the actual output:

[image: http://d.pr/i/eZYP]

I have a feeling I can't div target inside tables.. can I?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Why not put the div IN the `tr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a div around a tr tag. You can instead put that id on the tr and use something like this.

```
$.get("points_view.php?eid=<?php echo $eid;?>", function(data){
    $("#points_details_data").after(data);
});
```

A better solution would be to have thead, tbody and tfoot tags to wrap table head, body and footer and putting the id on the table. Then the ajax call will change to

```
$.get("points_view.php?eid=<?php echo $eid;?>", function(data){
    $("#points_details_data tbody").append(data);
});
```

Comment: the div around the rows is going to brake your html. @3coins is right.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<div>` tags inside your `<td>` tags..

then you can use:

```
var id = <?php echo $eid;?>;

document.getElementById("points_details_data").innerHTML = id;
```